# Appstore review

Tags: ios, app-store

What happens if I submit an app and then (for example after 3 days) when the app is in state "Waiting for review", I reject the binary and I submit a new update? The approval time is influenced and restart or not? Example: if the approval time is 7 days and I reject-resubmit after 3 days, I have to wait for 7 days more to see my app approved or just 4 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Josh suggested, and I can confirm, if you update and resubmit, your position in the review queue is forfeit and your app will reenter the queue at the end - so you can expect to wait the typical 7 or so days for review.

Whether or not you wish to do this is a matter of your own discretion, but to my thinking would be based on how critical the error is. Better to wait and deliver a seamless product to users than deliver something with significant bugs that will put potential users off once-and-for-all (my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but my guess based on knowing how Apple is with these kinds of things would be that you must wait another full 7 days. You could always just release the new binary as an update as soon as your app is accepted. Unless of course, there is some major problem with it, but in that case, it probably won't get accepted anyway. Sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the state of submission of an app, if you reject your submitted binary before approval, your new submission will **ALWAYS** be reset and everything starts all over again. Now, to *jump* the queue there is an option to expedite the review process by sending a request to apple via this [link](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/?topic=expedite)